# how to make file server use RAM cache

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

most file server systems like TrueNAS or Proxmox, when using their software raid, will cache files in system memory to increase performance. also, they will use as much ram as available. this has obvious performance gains. windows server, i think, will do the same thing when using their storage spaces setup.

my question is, is it possible to have windows server do the same thing when it is being used as a virtual machine with a virtual disk? presently we are using one box to run 3 different file servers, as is a common practice, with each of the 3 file server VM's having their own virtual disk to store and serve files. well, virtual hard drives aren't the fastest thing on the planet. however, windows server, it seems, doesn't use RAM to cache files when storage spaces isn't being used. i can tell, because each of the servers utizilses about 4-5 GB of system RAM, regardless of how much we assign to each VM. DDR4 ram would be a nice performance hop compared to a virtual disk. the dell perc has a a GB or two cache built in, but one video editor can fill that. we are using windows server 2019.

jared

Comment: What is the purpose of 3 VMs on one host, each serving different files? I can think of a few possible reasons, but please explain the design more.